# Issues getting captured imaged from Camera to be viewed as an ImageView object. - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-imageview, android-fileprovider

I want to create an application that when the user clicks a button, it takes you to the phone's default camera app, captures a pictures and brings it back to the activity's imageview object to be displayed in the activity. Below is the code I have.

PROBLEM: The issue is that the image is not displaying in the imageview. It comes back to the activity after taking a pictures, but it does not display it.

AndroidManifest.xml has the below added:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
...

   <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.application.hidden.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-files-path name="my_images" path="/" />
</paths>
```

MainActivity.java

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = this.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );

        imagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

@OnClick({R.id.takePicture, R.id.pic})
    void onTakePic() {
        changeImageLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
        System.out.println("Setting up for capture, clicked on camera");
        Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            //Create a file to store the image
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
            if(photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getContext(),"com.application.hidden.provider", photoFile);
                pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, RESULT_LOAD_CAMERA_IMG);
            }
        }
    }

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            case RESULT_LOAD_CAMERA_IMG:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Glide.with(this).load(imagePath).into(listingImage);
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        isNewImageAdded = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Would appreciate any suggestions or help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your file path to file object, use new File(imagepath), instead of just imagepath inside glide.

Comment: The image is still not displaying for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to capture an image from the camera and store in local memory and then load from memory.

If you just want to display captured image in imageview then follow the below way.

For open camera:

```
intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
```

Then in onActivityResult result:

```
if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```